# Any way to troubleshoot slow folder access on particular folder?

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I have a very simple setup:

A programs and a games folder in my windows directory (SSD). That combined wint Start10 from Stardock (windows 7 like start menu). I pin these folders there and the right hand side of the menu turns into folder contents when selected (and most programs, like steam, just turn into a list of most recent X games).

Thing is, my games folder (despite being in the same place and with like 6 shortcuts in it) loads MUCH slower than my programs folder (with a bit more stuff, but all just .lnk).

Is there a way for me to troubleshoot as to why this particular thing is happening. The difference is easily perceivable.

Could this be a Start10 thing?

EDIT: It goes away for a while after my first access, if that helps.

Comment: this happens when you [use Windows defender](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/case-of-the-slow-downloads-folder/). try other AV suites or exclude the game folder from real time scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Sound to me like that folder might not have indexing enabled for what you are trying to access. Indexing increases file search speed and allows quick display of data on the drive at the cost of some disk space. With indexing disabled it would increase speed of searches/displaying of the data in that folder.

Below is a link with more information on how to setup indexing

http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows-10-index-files-improve-search,2-54.html